# In the proof for Urysohn's lemma, why isn't "$x\in {U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\leq r$, and if $x\notin {U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\geq r$" true?

Tags: general-topology

[This](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m54x12/m54lecture20.pdf) proof of Urysohn's lemma states that if $x\in \overline{U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\leq r$, and if $x\notin \overline{U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\geq r$. *This portion is given on page 4*.

Isn't this also true for open sets $U$? 
Isn't **$x\in {U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\leq r$, and if $x\notin {U_{r}}$, then $f(x)\geq r$** also true, where $U$ is an open set that is not clopen?

EDIT: Justification:

1. If $x\in U_{r}$, then $f(x)\leq r$ quite clearly.
2. If $x\notin U_{r}$, but $\in$ every open set whose index is higher than $r$, then $f(x)=r$ (as the greatest lower bound of the indices is mapped to). Else, the $f(x)>r$.

$x,U_{r},\overline{U}$, all belong to **normal** space $X$.

EDIT: **Why this is relevant in the proof is:**

Let $(a,b)$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, if $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ should also be open. $f^{-1}(a,b)$ contains points that are present in open sets $U_{r}\setminus U_{a}$ such that $a<r<b$. $f^{-1}(a,b)$ can't contain points in $\overline{U_{a}}\setminus U_{a}$ as then $\{a\}$ would be included in the mapping.

If what I'm saying is true- that if $x\notin U_{r}$, but $\in$ every open set whose index is higher than $r$ then $f(x)\geq r$, then also the mapping $f$ will contain $\{a\}$.

So what exactly is $f^{-1}(a,b)$?? This seems to be a direct contradiction of the fact that $f^{-1}(a,b)$ contains points that are present in open sets $U_{r}\setminus U_{a}$ such that $a<r<b$.

**$f^{-1}(a,b)$ seems to contain points in sets satisfying the following condition: the greatest lower bound of the indices of the sets is not $a$.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: note that 4(b) already says literally that $x \notin U_r$ implies $f(x) \ge r$. There is no closure in the second statement.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- could you kindly read the edited part of the question, where I've explained why this is potentially problematic for my understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that if $x\in U_r$, then $f(x)\le r$, and if $x\notin U_r$, then $f(x)\ge r$; this just isn't very useful for the proof of Uryson's lemma.

**Added after OP’s edit of the question:** Note that $U_a$ is defined only for $a\in\Bbb Q$, so you want to start with an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $a,b\in\Bbb Q$. Recall that

$$f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\inf\{p\in\Bbb Q:x\in U_p\}\;.$$

Suppose that $f(x)\in(a,b)$, so that $a<f(x)<b$. Clearly $a<f(x)$ implies that $x\notin U_a$. However, I claim that we can say more: $$x\notin\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}\;.$$

> Suppose, on the contrary, that $$x\in\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}\;.$$ For any rational $p>a$ there is a rational $q\in(a,p)$, so $x\in\operatorname{cl}U_q\subseteq U_p$. Thus, $$\{p\in\Bbb Q:x\in U_p\}\supseteq\Bbb Q\cap(a,\to)\;.$$ On the other hand, $x\notin U_a$, and for each rational $p\le a$ we have $U_p\subseteq U_a$ and hence $x\notin U_p$, so in fact 
>   $$\{p\in\Bbb Q:x\in U_p\}=\Bbb Q\cap(a,\to)\;,$$ and $f(x)=\inf\{p\in\Bbb Q:x\in U_p\}=\inf\big(\Bbb Q\cap(a,\to)\big)=a\notin(a,b)$. This is impossible, so $x$ cannot belong to $\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}$.

Since $b>\inf\{p\in\Bbb Q:x\in U_p\}$, there is a $p\in\Bbb Q$ such that $p<b$ and $x\in U_p$; thus, $$x\in\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\;.$$

Putting the pieces together, we see that

$$x\in\left(\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\right)\setminus\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}\;.$$

Conversely, suppose that

$$x\in\left(\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\right)\setminus\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}\;.$$

Since $x\in\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}$, there is a rational $p<b$ such that $x\in U_p$, and it follows at once that $f(x)\le p<b$. Since $x\notin\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}$, there is a rational $p>a$ such that $x\notin\operatorname{cl}U_p$ and hence $x\notin U_p$, and it follows that $f(x)\ge p>a$. Thus, $f(x)\in(a,b)$, and we’ve shown that

$$f^{-1}\big[(a,b)\big]=\left(\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\right)\setminus\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}\;.$$

$\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}$ is open, and $\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p>a\}$ is closed, so their difference, $f^{-1}\big[(a,b)\big]$, is open, just as it should be. Since this is the case for all open intervals $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints, and these form a base for the topology of $\Bbb R$, it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Brian, could you kindly read the edited portion of the question? I've mentioned why this is relevant to the proof of Urysohn's lemma. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayush: Done: I’ve given you an explicit description of the inverse image under $f$ of an arbitrary open interval in $\Bbb R$ with rational endpoints. (It’s enough to consider those intervals, since they form a base for the topology of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: Just one further question. You said $x\notin \bigcap \{\text{cl } U_{p}:p\in \Bbb{Q} \text { and } p>a\}$. But then again, the condition $x\notin \bigcap \{U_{p}:p\in \Bbb{Q} \text { and } p>a\}$ is also true for the very same reasons! So why should we give one condition preferential treatment over the other? Clearly $ \bigcup \{U_{p}:p\in \Bbb{Q} \text { and } p<b\}\setminus \bigcap \{ U_{p}:p\in \Bbb{Q} \text { and } p>a\}$ is not an open set!

Comment: @Ayush: First, we generally prefer the stronger statement. For any collection $\mathscr{A}$ of subsets of a space it’s true that $$\bigcap_{A\in\mathscr{A}}\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq\bigcap\mathscr{A}\;,$$ so $x\notin\bigcap_{A\in\mathscr{A}}\operatorname{cl}A$ implies that $x\notin\bigcap\mathscr{A}$; in general the opposite implication does not hold. Secondly, I wanted to demonstrate very clearly that $f^{-1}\big[(a,b)\big]$ is open. One way to do this is to show that it can be written as $V\setminus F$, where $V$ is open and $F$ is closed. An intersection of closed sets is always ...

Comment: ... closed; an intersection of open sets need not be.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Brian for your time and patience. I realise I deviated somewhat from the original proof and you made even that deviation coherent.

Comment: @Ayush: No problem; you’re very welcome.

Comment: Brian, one more question. Why can't $x\in \bigcup\{\text { cl } U_{p}: p\in\Bbb{Q} \text{ and } p<b\}$? Note the closure on $U_{p}$.

Comment: @Ayush: Essentially the same reason as before: $$\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\subseteq\bigcup\{\operatorname{cl}U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}\;,$$ so $$x\in\bigcup\{U_p:p\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<b\}$$ is the stronger statement, and in any case I want an open set there: that’s the $V$ of my earlier comment. (In fact the two unions are equal: if $p\in\Bbb Q$ and $p<b$, there is a $q\in\Bbb Q\cap(p,b)$, and $\operatorname{cl}U_p\subseteq U_q$. Thus, the union of the $\operatorname{cl}U_p$’s is contained in and hence equal to the union of the $U_p$’s. But that does nothing to ...

Comment: ... further the argument.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not relevant to the proof as it is given. The author claims

$x \in \overline{U_r}$ implies $f(x) \le r$.

$x \notin U_r$ implies $f(x) \ge r$.

He then proceeds to show that $O = f^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is open, not by showing it is directly equal to some $U_r$ or difference thereof, but by showing that for every $x$ in $O$, there are rationals $p < q$ (with $a < p < f(x) < q < b$) such that $U_q \setminus \overline{U_p}$ (which is open) is a neighbourhood of $x$ and that it is contained in $O$ (i.e. its image under $f$ is inside $(a,b)$). So this shows that each $x$ in $O$ is an interior point of $O$, ergo $O$ is open.

Analyzing the proof we can see that

$$f^{-1}[(a,b)] = \cup \left\{U_q \setminus \overline{U_{p}}\,: a < p < q < b, p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\right\} $$

which is a (countable) union of open sets.

The fact that $f[  U_q \setminus \overline{U_{p}} ] \subset [p,q]$ is a direct consequence of the 2 claims above, the first applied to $U_q$, showing $f(x) \le q$ (for some $x$ in the set $U_q \setminus \overline{U_{p}}$), because $x \in U_q \subset \overline{U_q}$; on the other hand $x \notin \overline{U_p}$ implies $x \notin U_p$, and then the second claim applies to show $f(x) \ge p$, so $f(x) \in [p,q] \subset (a,b)$